# Multiclass RGB image dataset ValueError: a must be greater than 0 unless no samples are taken

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am working an image dataset that consist of `2410 RGB image` data and belongs to two classes, i.e., `crops_class` and another is `grass_class`.  Crops class data contains `1210` and grass class contains `1200` image data. When I run the code I have faced an error that is

```
grass
(0, 2)
```

However when I run the data shape

```
df_data.shape
```

I find output

```
(2410, 2)

mtrand.pyx in numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.choice()
ValueError: a must be greater than 0 unless no samples are taken
```

My code:

```
df_data is not None and isinstance(df_data, pd.DataFrame) and not df_data.empty
>True
df_data.isnull().any()
>image_id    False
target      False
dtype: bool


SAMPLE_SIZE = (1200)
# Get a list of classes
target_list = os.listdir('/content/PlantDataset/')

for target in target_list:
    print(target)

# Filter out a target and take a random sample
temp = df_data[df_data['target'] == target]
print(temp.shape)
df=temp.sample(SAMPLE_SIZE, random_state=101)
# if it's the first item in the list
if target == target_list[0]:
    df_sample = df
else:
    # Concat the dataframes
    df_sample = pd.concat([df_sample, df], axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Error:

```
grass
(0, 2)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-7918c4242404> in <module>()
      8     temp = df_data[df_data['target'] == target]
      9     print(temp.shape)
---> 10     df=temp.sample(SAMPLE_SIZE, random_state=101)
     11     # if it's the first item in the list
     12     if target == target_list[0]:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in sample(self, n, frac, replace, weights, random_state, axis, ignore_index)
   5363             )
   5364 
-> 5365         locs = rs.choice(axis_length, size=n, replace=replace, p=weights)
   5366         result = self.take(locs, axis=axis)
   5367         if ignore_index:

mtrand.pyx in numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.choice()

ValueError: a must be greater than 0 unless no samples are taken
```

How may I solve this error ?

Comment: can you try `df=temp.sample(SAMPLE_SIZE, random_state=101, axis=1)`

Comment: Dear mentor, I tried it and still I find the same error @BijayRegmi

Comment: I think your dataframe `temp` is empty since its returning shape of `(0,2)` which means 0 rows but 2 columns.

Comment: that is why the error is being thrown. Also you are iterating through `targets` but only printing each value. In this statement `temp = df_data[df_data['target'] == target]` only last value of `targets` is being taken.

Comment: Dear mentor, thank You for Your cordial cooperation. I able to fix the problem. This is about the class name. I updated the class name crop and, grass instead of crop_class and grass_class. Now my code is running without any error. Thank You @BijayRegmi